# Choosing "Partition Key" in Cosmos DB collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection which will store at around 1 millions records monthly in cosmos db collection, which comes to 4-5 GB of data quarterly.
I want to create a partition key based on "EventType", but in this case also, each "EventType" reach up 10 GB limit within in a year.

So the next option for us to create a partition key based on "PayerNumber" field. But we may have 10,000 unique payer numbers.

Is it a good idea to choose this field("PayerNumber") to create a partition key? How many logical partitions are supported by Cosmos DB? Is there any limit to it?

Following is the sample json:

```
{
"PayerName": "XYZ",
"PayerNumber": "XYZ00000667",
"EventType": "CARD_BLOCK",
"EventTypeDescription": "CARD_BLOCK",
"ModifiedByUUID": "4f371d98-0e31-442b-9ff9-9dcf4a629640",
"ModifiedByUserName": "Postman",
"SubscriptionIsPayerAccountBased": false,
"Data": [
    {
        "AccountName": "XYZ",
        "AccountNumber": "XYZ00000667",
        "DriverName": "DSDSDS",
        "ExpiryDate": "2019-03-31",
        "PAN": "*******912068",
        "Status": "Active",
        "VRN": "FDFDFD"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to logical partitions in Cosmos DB. You should read [choosing the right partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey) article. You might want to create an artificial partition key, based on how your data will be spread.